# Android: Hidden ActionBar by accident

Tags: android, menu, tablet, android-actionbar

On Xooms and other tablets, my apps are by accident hiding the Actionbar, but I don't know how to get the ActionBar to show. I am trying to let the user press the Menu button when they don't have a physical menu button.

Here's my theme in styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

  <style name="TextViewStyled" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">    
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>         
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.22</item>   
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: The styles look fine. You might have done this a million times already, but you might want to look into your code.